# FormDate и Uploadifive

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Хочу отправить параллельно с файлом значения формы, вот что получилось, но оно почему то не работает. Подскажите в чем может быть моя ошибка ?

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addcomment').submit(function() {
       $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'         : false,
        'formData'     : {'pole' : $("#wall").val()},
        'queueID'      : 'queue',
        'uploadScript' : 'insertcomment.php',       
    });         
    });
  });     
</script>
```

Вот скрипт который должен отправлять файл и значения формы обработчику.

```
     <form method="post" id="addcomment">
   <div class="textarea">
  <textarea  class="input" id="wall" s placeholder="What is new ?"></textarea><br></div>
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Post" />
 </form>
```

А вот сама форма, подскажите что я здесь сделал неправильно ? Помогите разобраться! Заранее  спасибо.

Comment: Там, я так понял, метод `$('#file_upload').uploadifive({})` с параметрами инициализирует форму загрузки, а метод `$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload')` уже загружает файл с помощью созданной формы

Comment: А как сделать так что бы правильно было ? На данный момент при клике на кнопку происходит только обновление страницы

Comment: @OverLoader вы можете форму показать? К тому же вам нужно убрать стандартное действие с формы, примерно вот так: http://pastebin.com/BNWbs7tJ

Comment: Он отправляет форму только с наличием файла а нужно что бы отправлял форму и без наличия так такового, в чем может быть на этот раз проблема ?)